# Apply an action to every object in group for Phaser js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

As it says, in Phaser.js how can you apply an action for each object inside a group. I want to apply the following lines to each item:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(something, platforms);
game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, something, gameOver, null, this);
something.body.velocity.x = -120;
```

"Something" is the object name but my group name is called "obstacleGroup". I want to do this as I have another function making new objects to the group all the time so I don't necessarily know what they are being called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Group.forEach to iterate the objects in the group and call a function on them:

```
obstacleGroup.forEach(function(item) {
    game.physics.arcade.collide(item, platforms);
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, item, gameOver);
    item.body.velocity.x = -120;
}, this);
```

Comment: @imcg the latest phaser version requires you to pass `this` as the second argument to `forEach`. I updated your answer to include this.

Answer (score 12):

Group.forEach is one such iteration method you could use (as @imcg pointed out before me). However you're using it for Arcade Physics collision, and that can take a Group as the parameters. So you could collide everything in your Group vs. platforms with just:

`game.physics.arcade.collide(obstacleGroup, platforms);`

Once, in your update loop.

Same works for `overlap`.